# ZeroMQ Pub/Sub on Unreliable Connection

Tags: zeromq

I've implemented a simple ZeroMQ Pub/Sub architecture using zmq 4.0.4.  Everything works great, sub's receive messages from pub's.

All is great and I rejoiced with many beer.

HOWEVER .. 24 hours after keeping having the sub & pub sit idle over an unreliable network connection the sub wasn't able to receive any messages from the pub.  I was able to reproduce the issue by blocking the sub's connection port with the pub temporarily after connection with the pub.  Not only did the sub miss all messages during the time behind the firewall (expected due to the nature of pub/sub) but ALSO it failed to receive ANY messages from pub after that.

A similar (but old) question was posted that actually had the sub throw an exception when this happened.  But appeared to be a bug that was fixed.  [ZMQ Pub-Sub Program Failure When Losing Network Connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333630/zmq-pub-sub-program-failure-when-losing-network-connectivity)

**Short of implementing a heartbeat to determine if the connection is severed is there any way for a sub to auto-reconnect when the connection is severed with a pub?**

Comment: If it's not auto-reconnecting, then your only other option is a heartbeat.  The reconnection should be part of the "magic" of a ZMQ socket, if it's not happening then something is falling down somewhere.

Comment: Implemented a heartbeat and it works like a charm .. however I'm surprised that ZMQ doesn't throw an error (or event) when it can't reconnect

Comment: ZMQ is very much a toolset for building communication systems more than a full communication system in and of itself, so no doubt this was seen as the responsibility of the developer rather than of the library... but, it's a fairly open community so if someone were to want to add this functionality to the library it'd probably be there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posted an issue on the [zmq core github page](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) and it was answered by the projects owner.

> It is possible that the PUB socket sees the error while the SUB socket does
>   not.
>
> The ZMTP RFC has a proposal for heartbeating that would solve this problem.
>   The current best solution is for PUB sockets to send heartbeats (e.g. 1 per
>   second) when traffic is low, and for SUB sockets to disconnect / reconnect
>   if they stop getting these.

Implemented a simple heartbeat and it worked like a charm.

[More Info Here](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1199)

Comment: I know its way late, but would you mind posing a snippet of the hearbeat code? Pretty please?

Comment: sure thing!  It's actually in the library that I wrote when I encountered this issue. https://github.com/moappi/zeromq.process .  Check out the heartbeat section or feel free to use the library if you're hoping to process something using ZeroMQ

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little cheat, just put it on a timer to send every 60 seconds or what-not from your SUB side.

```
std::string ping = "PING";
controller->setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ping.c_str(), ping.length());
```

This will both have the effect of keeping the TCP connection alive, and also returning any TCP disconnection causing ZeroMQ to automatically re-connect.

Comment: This may work, but subscriptions accumulate even if they are the same. You have to set an unsubscribe for every subscribe. It could be difficult to ensure that the number of active subscriptions is always >0 while also not growing linearly.